# Events in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, navigation, jquery-events

I'm trying for some time to make events work, but they do not work, I'm trying to look for any reaction with alert or `console.log` but nothing to do, no reaction. I tried to change the selectors, same result. I also try to introduce them with `$(document).ready` or `$("#mypage").("pagecreate",` ...

Still trying with jsfiddle, it works perfectly but on my file from the browser, nothing.

I have only swipe that works.

Scrollstop and navigate does not work.

```
$('#neww').on("scrollstop", function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
     recept2();
 }
```

[Looking for a way to dynamically add more lists to the bottom of jQuery Mobile listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623636/looking-for-a-way-to-dynamically-add-more-lists-to-the-bottom-of-jquery-mobile-l)

```
$("#mypanel").on("navigate", function (event, data) {
var direction = data.state.direction;

if (direction == 'back') {
$("#mypanel").panel("close");
   console.log(direction);
}
});
```

[how to control back button event in Jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-to-control-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile/18213393#18213393)

Comment: `scollstop` should be bound to `$(document)` and `navigate` to `$(window)`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24728709/1771795

Comment: Nice Omar, thank you very much
It works very well, my popup closes perfectly but How do I block the return of the old page?

Comment: This is another issue. Pls post a new question with details :)